Audio recording in front-end
I create a Vue application (using Vue 3.4.21).
I am interested in allow user to record an audio, and managed to create a component that does it, and saving it to local user machine.
Here you can see the snippet I created.
I would like to add the following functionalities:

Sending chunks of audio (every X ms) to back-end (via web-sockets?), so I can process it with Whisper and return to front-end transcript of the recording in real time.
When record ends, send the entire blob to some api so I can save the mp3 on server.


I liked it. may need it for my project. Do you much better version of it ?

I finally do not send chunks, but the entire file. I do it with: const blob = new Blob(recordChunks, { type: 'audio/mp3' }); fileToUpload = new File([blob], fileName); and then add it to a form that I submit to server.

Great. I have ainisa.com project with audio recording available. But in chrome extension the audio recorder plugin was not allowed. So I was searching for another solutions. Seems your solution will help me.
